# Where and how are custom startup commands configured in Linux?

Tags: linux, init

I'd like to add custom startup commands (for example starting a process, registering to a registration server, downloading a configuration file) to the Linux startup process. Those commands should be triggered on startup only. What is the standard/appropriate way to do this?

EDIT: Is /etc/profile the right place to trigger such things?

EDIT2: I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: `/etc/profile` is for starting a new terminal session; it has nothing to do with booting.

Comment: Linux is developed in a decentralized manner.  The people who write your init scripts are quite separate from the people who write your kernel.  As such, different distributions have different init scripts.

Comment: Startup of what? Do you mean "during or after boot"? Do you mean "During or after I log in"? If log in, do you mean "log in to a local terminal"? Do you mean "Log in via a remote shell"? Do you mean "Log in from [xkg]dm"? Do you mean "Start up X"?

Comment: Linux is a kernel. You and I run an operating system that uses a Linux kernel, Gnu libraries and tools, X11 Windowing system, Gnome this and Openoffice that. As all (most) of there components fulfilling the Gnu project (Gnu is a meta project to make all software be Free Software), we can call the operating systems Gnu with Linux or Gnu/Linux (There are other systems that use Linux, and other kernels that can be used with Gnu).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No-one can answer this question without knowing which flavour of Linux you are using.

Under Debian (and Debian-based system such as Ubuntu), you put your startup script called `foo` to the directory `/etc/init.d`, then you call `update-rc.d foo defaults`. Be sure to consult the man page before so you understand what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

The [init](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) system handles startup.  That said, however, this question belongs on superuser.com or serverfault.com.

Comment: Most system use init, however, for example Slackware uses `/etc/rc.d/*` system but still support use of init!

Comment: Another example: Ubuntu uses Upstart.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson, they don't even support init scripts?

Comment: @Anders: Upstart has legacy support for `init` scripts.

Comment: No, the question doesn't belong on superuser or serverfault; it is a legitimate programming question which people packaging software for Linux need to know the answer to.

Answer (score 1):

One simple place where to put your script (although not all distributions use it) to be run at system boot time is /etc/rc.local

Answer (score 0):

It depends exactly which distribution you're using. On redhat-like systems, you place your service file in /etc/init.d then use chkconfig --add to add it, and it will start up on boot at the appropriate time.

Some Linux systems also have a "cron" which supports the @reboot extension which runs the job when the system starts up. You can install crontabs using "crontab" or (as a very useful Redhat extension) in directory /etc/cron.d. See man(5) crontab, man(8) cron and man(1) crontab for more details.

If it's a constantly-running process, I'd install it as a sysv-style service.